# Easiest way to get MAC address from a (non-local) IP address in IPv4

Tags: c#, windows, networking, ip-address, mac-address

Is there an easy way to get a MAC address of a machine connected to my app via a TCP/IPv4 socket?

*Or in more general terms:*

If I have the IP address, what is the best way to get the corresponding MAC address in IPv4?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148778/how-do-i-access-arp-protocol-information-through-net

Comment: @John Saunders - Hmmm. I sort of agree. Problem is that the answers to that question...leave a bit to be desired. If we get good ones here, they should probably be merged.

Comment: Note that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238963/query-arp-cache-to-get-mac-id, while about Java rather than C#, has much more useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the ARP table's job to keep that information. The best thing to do would be to read it out of there.

You might consider reading the answers to [Query ARP cache to get MAC ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238963/query-arp-cache-to-get-mac-id). The questioner was using Java, but otherwise its your identical question.

Comment: @John Saunders - But that's all he can do.

Comment: @T.E.D. It's all he can do, but it's not what he _wants_ to do, so the answer is, "you can't do what you want to do".

Comment: +1 thanks T.E.D. - I will try that and perhapse post some nice code

Comment: I see nothing in his question that implies to me he is asking, "How do I get the MAC addresses for everything on the internet"? He seems to agree...

Comment: @T.E.D. : tried that once, but only resulted in an OutOfMemory-Exception ;-)

Comment: @T.E.D.: I see in another comment he says the client is always on the same network. I tried to remove the downvote, it you'll need to edit your answer before SO lets me do that.

Comment: Heh. April fools day is really the perfect day for me to get the accepted answer, with a score of 0. :-)

Answer (score 6):

MAC addresses are used only for the next hop.  This basically means the client's original MAC address won't be visible after it's first hop.  In the general sense, if you are not on the same physical segment as the client, you have NO way of taking an IP and getting the MAC (or vice/versa).

Comment: Thanks! I almost forgot! But lucky me, the client is always on the same network!

Answer (score 3):

You can't, without having something (or the client itself) on that other network.

MAC addresses are used on the second layer, the data-link layer, of the [OSI model for networking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).  MACs are specific to Ethernet.  When you get to the Internet, IP addresses are used.  Not everything connected to the Internet uses Ethernet at lower layers.

There are also other protocols other than IP that can be used.

Basically, your computer only knows what is on its physical network segment.  If it has to go outside for anything else, it only knows the MAC of the gateway to get there.