# How to get remote machines mac addresses java

Tags: java, ip, mac-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Query ARP cache to get MAC ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238963/query-arp-cache-to-get-mac-id)

I need to get the mac addresses of all the remote machines connected to my home network. i can read the mac address of my own machine using this code below but i don't know how to get the mac addresses of other machines on my network. or is it possible or not.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
byte[] mac = ni.getHardwareAddress();

for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
  System.out.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "");
}
}
}
```

output  (MyComputer's 6byte mac address)
30-60-77-12-cd-99

Comment: For what purpose? There's nothing useful you can do with a MAC address in Java except display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get remote machines mac addresses

You cannot do that - not in the general case. [MAC addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) are only available for machines in the same physical network segment. Those machines communicate directly with each other using the [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) protocol to "translate" IP addresses to physical (MAC) addresses.

As soon as an IP router or any other [Layer-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_reference_model#Layer_3%3a_network_layer) device is crossed, any MAC information is generally lost.

Bottom line: you cannot get the MAC address of a remote node over the Internet - you cannot even do that in any moderately sized private network, as implemented in e.g. most medium to large companies.

Comment: This is also why wake-on-LAN packets need to come from a machine in the same physical net segment.