# How to calculate mac address from ip address

Tags: networking, ip, mac-address

Hi I'd like to know how can I calculate a Mac address from a ip address manually.

For example if I've this ip:

192.168.0.1/24

What's the mac address?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address

Comment: You can't. Not a real question.

Comment: Related question that might help OP (and at least gives more explanation): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238963/query-arp-cache-to-get-mac-id (only useful for local network, of course)

Comment: Use Address Resolution Protocol..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot calculate the Mac address from the IP address.  They originate from different sources.

- It's generally the hardware that determines its MAC address
- It's the configuration of the network that determines its IP address.