# How to get Client Mac Id using web application?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I am developing one web application, in that I need to restrict users.

Some particular system can only access my web application because of some security process. I tried but I can get Server system Mac address only.

So please let me find out the solution.I hope someone will find me the solution.

Comment: can you post code,just to see how you connects to client

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830336/java-get-uuid-or-mac-address-from-client

Comment: @reto yeah off course they are connected in same LAN.

Comment: @AkashShinde if i use that code means it wont get client system MAC address. It just gets only server system MAC address.

Comment: You will not get the mac address from a browser (http session) just the ip, and you cant rely on the ip as you may get a routers ip. Why cant you just use user authentication ?

Comment: @KennethClark Actually my need was my web application needs to run in particular registered systems that is why am struggling

Comment: why don't you use UUID instead of mac address then?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your security requirements? Is it system to system, or any "registered user"?

Comment: @KennethClark in my application, there is a registration process in that they want to choose how many connections they need to use,based on that we want to provide connections.

Comment: @KennethClark he is trying to restrict the user's system to access the application with in the LAN.he is try to identify the user with in the LAN is having the permission to access the application\

Comment: @AkashShinde using UUID is not suits for me because i need to run my application in particular systems only not in any other systems.

Comment: If you are within an internal lan you could potentially control access via Apache (htaccess or directory access) this works at ip address level. This will just allow pc's to connect, you will need further authentication such as ldap and provide role level security if you need to restrict usecases within your application