# How to prevent restrict access to a web application to authorized devices only?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have developed an MVC web app. Right now, the client using this app in office area. The client has requested that no one should use this app on any device except the office's PC/tablets.

Now problem is, it's a web app, so how can I put restrictions that nobody can use this app from the outside of the office or with devices other with than office's PC/Tablets?

Comment: If you need it be used only in an environment deploy it in the environment alone `(e.g) portal applications`

Comment: It will may helps you : http://forums.iis.net/t/1153158.aspx?How+to+restrict+a+IIS7+web+site+to+a+specific+range+of+IP+address+

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach to that problem is maintain a database of authorized [MAC addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address). The next part is harder, because Java provides no mechanism to get the remote mac address. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238963/query-arp-cache-to-get-mac-id). Given that I would require users authenticate to the web application, if an authorized user is on the device you could consider that device authorized. If that doesn't work, you might be able to use [white-listed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist#LAN_whitelists) IP address ranges. If that doesn't work I think you're back to MAC addresses.